# How to log particular classes to another log file in Spring Boot

Tags: java, logging, spring-boot

I have simple log setup in application.properties:

```
logging.file = logs/debug.log
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL = DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type = TRACE
```

I have a package `co.myapp.notifier`. I want all classes of this package to log to `logs/notifier.log`. I tried 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9652239
and 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/728351
with no luck. 
In all cases the messages goes to my debug.log

Comment: By default spring uses logback so solutions for log4j will obviously not work. If you want to change where the stuff is logged then add your own `logback.xml` file for configuring logback, you cannot do this with the basic configuration support in Spring Boot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to do that, you will need your own `logback.xml` file.

```
<configuration>

<!-- Normal debug log appender -->
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>debug.log</file>

    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

<appender name="virtuallab" type="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
   <file value="Logs/virtuallab.log"/>
   <appendToFile value="true"/>
   <maxSizeRollBackups value="5"/>
   <maximumFileSize value="5MB"/>
   <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
   <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
   <encoder>
     <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
   </encoder>
</appender>

<!-- Setup the root category, add the appenders and set the default level -->
  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>

<!-- Specify the level specific to co.myapp.notifier -->
<logger name="co.myapp.notifier">
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="virtuallab" />
</logger>

</configuration>
```

If you need a console log, you may need to add it as well. [Here](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html) is the docs and read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987289/quartz-keeps-putting-its-log-on-all-my-log-files) also.