# How do I turn off the "NioEndPoint" Logging in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java.util.logging

I am working on a Spring Boot web application where I add a long running process to a ScheduledExecutorService.

To make sure it is acting the way I think I am using System.out.println() for debugging that long running process.

My problem is I keep getting these

> NioEndpoint    FINER | timeout completed: keys processed=1; now=1492721057929; nextExpiration=1492721057927; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false  {timeout() / 18}
>   04:44.714 NioEndpoint    FINER | timeout completed: keys processed=0; now=1492721058713; nextExpiration=1492721058712; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false  {timeout() / 17}
>   04:44.931 NioEndpoint    FINER | timeout completed: keys processed=1; now=1492721058931; nextExpiration=1492721058929; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false  {timeout() / 18}
>   04:44.718 NioEndpoint    FINER | timeout completed

Messages spammed in the output window, which makes deciphering the other logging impossible.

I tried adding `logging.level.root=ERROR` to application.properties, but that did not remove them.

How do I get them not to appear and what do they signify ?

Dependency Tree Below:

```
org.springframework:gs-uploading-files:jar:0.1.0
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.0.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |  \- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.11:compile
|  |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.11:compile
|  |  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.24:compile - version managed from 1.6.6; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.24:compile
|  |  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.24:compile - version managed from 1.7.22; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.24:compile
|  |  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.24:compile - version managed from 1.7.22; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.24:compile
|  |  |     \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.24:compile - version managed from 1.7.22; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
|  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.11:compile
|  |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.11:compile
|  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.11:compile
|  |  |     \- (org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.11:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.4.Final:compile
|  |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
|  |  |  +- (org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.3:compile (version managed from 1.3.1)
|  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.0.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.0.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
|  |     +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |     +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |     +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |     +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |     +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
|  |     |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |     \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |  +- ognl:ognl:jar:3.0.8:compile
|  |  |  +- (org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile - version managed from 3.18.1-GA; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  +- org.unbescape:unbescape:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.24:compile - version managed from 1.6.6; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.24:compile
|  \- nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:jar:1.4.0:compile
|     +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:2.4.9:compile (version managed from 2.4.3)
|     \- (org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 2.1.4.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:test
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:test
|  |  \- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:test - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:test
|  |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:test - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  \- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:test - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
|  |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test
|  |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:test
|  |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:test
|  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.24:test - version managed from 1.7.16; omitted for duplicate)
|  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
|  |  \- (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test - version managed from 1.1; omitted for duplicate)
|  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:2.6.0:test
|  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
|  |  +- (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test - version managed from 1.1; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
|  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
|  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
|  |  \- (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test - version managed from 1.1; omitted for duplicate)
|  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.4.0:test
|  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
|  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - scope updated from test; omitted for duplicate)
|  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:test
|     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:test - omitted for duplicate)
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
|  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.7:compile
|  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.7:compile
|  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc:jar:2.6.1.RELEASE:compile
|     +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-core:jar:2.6.1.RELEASE:compile
|     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|     |  +- org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:jar:0.23.0.RELEASE:compile
|     |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.3.5.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
|     |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.3.5.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
|     |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.3.5.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
|     |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.3.5.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
|     |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.3.5.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
|     |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.3.5.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
|     |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.24:compile - version managed from 1.7.22; omitted for duplicate)
|     |  +- (org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.13.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|     |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
|     |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.0.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
|     |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.0.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
|     |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.0.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
|     |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.24:compile - version managed from 1.7.10; omitted for duplicate)
|     |  +- org.atteo:evo-inflector:jar:1.2.1:compile
|     |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile - version managed from 2.8.7; omitted for duplicate)
|     |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.24:compile - version managed from 1.7.10; omitted for duplicate)
|     |  \- (org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.24:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
|     +- (org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.3.5.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
|     +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|     +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile - version managed from 2.8.7; omitted for duplicate)
|     +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.24:compile - version managed from 1.7.10; omitted for duplicate)
|     \- (org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.24:compile - scope updated from runtime; omitted for duplicate)
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
|  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.0.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.3.5.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.9:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.5.11:compile
|  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.5.11:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
|  |     +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.0.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
|  |     +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.3.5.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
|  |     \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
|  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
|  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
|  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile
|  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
|  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
|  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
|  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
|  |     \- (org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
|  |  +- (org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- (org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- (dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- (org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- (org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  \- (org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile - version managed from 3.18.1-GA; omitted for duplicate)
|  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
|  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.11.1.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.13.1.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.3.5.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.0.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.24:compile - version managed from 1.7.10; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.24:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.0.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.3.5.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.0.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.0.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.3.5.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.0.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.0.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.3.5.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.3.5.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.3.5.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.24:compile - version managed from 1.7.10; omitted for duplicate)
|  |  \- (org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.24:compile - scope updated from runtime; omitted for duplicate)
|  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
|     \- (org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.9:compile - omitted for duplicate)
+- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.193:compile
+- LIUM:LIUM_SpkDiarization:jar:8.4.1:compile
\- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
```

Comment: can you print the logging dependencies present in your application?

Comment: google maven dependency tree

Comment: @bulltorious, your dependency tree seems fine. Can you post the code snippet where you are using `ScheduledExecutorService` that might help me understand what's going on!

Answer (score 13):

You did not provide details about logging configuration in your application so it is difficult to identify the actual issue. Setting following properties in `application.properties` should block `NioEndpoint` log messages.

```
logging.level.org.apache.tomcat=INFO
logging.level.org.apache.tomcat.util.net=WARN
```

You can find details about `NioEndpoint.java` at [tomcat github](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/59e760e11bba8adac94b107eb90c422f572637bf/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/NioEndpoint.java). There is a `timeout` method in that class which logs this message.

**EDIT**

Log messages you have posted contain `FINER` log messages which means you are using `java.util.logging`. If you have configured spring-boot for `java.util.logging` then add following properties in `logging.properties` file. Please check if your application is using jdk/jre provided `logging.properties` file or custom `logging.properties` file and modify appropriate file.

```
org.apache.tomcat.level=INFO
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.level=WARNING
```

If you do not want to control it by package level logging configuration (which is preferred) then you can set the global logging level and ConsoleHandler/FileHandler logging level to INFO in `logging.properties` file.

```
.level=INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=INFO
```

Please note the log levels for `java.util.logging` are bit different. You cannot set ERROR here but you can set SEVERE which is the highest level. Please check details at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Level.html

Comment: This had no effect.  Added dependency tree.

Comment: Can you please provide your logging configuration.

Comment: logging.level.org.apache.tomcat=ERROR
logging.level.org.apache.tomcat.util.net=ERROR

Comment: I am looking for details regarding logback or java.util.logger configurations you have in your application. Details of LogManager or logging.properties, logging.config setup. Please see my EDIT above and try by adding  properties in your logging.properties file.

Comment: @bulltorious, I have tested the configuration, I have provided in EDIT section of my answer, and this configuration works fine for controlling "NioEndpoint FINER" log messages. Please verify and let me know. Thanks.

Comment: still not working...my logging.properties is .level=OFF java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=OFF

Comment: My sample app is working fine with that settings. However I had to set following two properties in VM arguments to read from logging.properties. -Dorg.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem=none
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=F:\project\sample\src\main\resources\logging.properties

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the solution proposed by abaghel you can also achieve your needs by logging the long running process into a separate file.

You can replace the `System.out.println` logging by standard log calls and configure an appender to log your particular class into a specific place (find [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31947163/2065796)).

Having such configuration you'll always have your logs in separate place independently from logging levels which are set for the rest of the classes.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same issue, It got fixed when i added exclusion of starter-logging as below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

or

Add below config in application.properties logging.level.org.apache.tomcat=ERROR logging.level.org.apache.catalina=ERROR

Comment: So your solution for not logging one particular message is to disable _all_ logging?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas definitely not... u can always do logging from application level using logger statement,  excluding default logging will not stop all the loggings .. we can still always use logging where ever we need in application..  i believe thats the way we can avoid writing all the unnecessary logs to file. i think there is also the way to set log severe levels for such logging to control as well

Comment: Excluding default logging will disable everything using the default logger. The OP only wants to remove a single log statement; I'm pretty sure this solution will remove a lot more than just that one statement.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas As i said we can also control logging levels from application.properties. it worked for me... If u wanna give you a try and let me know

Removed exclusion and added the below config in application.properties 

logging.level.org.apache.tomcat=ERROR
logging.level.org.apache.catalina=ERROR